# How would I allow my search to be comma separated if the user wanted to search this way?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

How would I make it so that it allows the user to search using comma separated values (`inventory.InventoryItemID`) if they want to? For example they input in search bar `34,35` and the respective data shows up?

I know I have to use `whereIn()` and added a `,` at the end of the function but I'm still not quite sure how it's done correctly.  I've looked online but some answers seem a little vague.  How would I be able to achieve this?

```
$values = explode(',',$searchKeyword);

    $this->db
        ->where('inventoryitem.InventoryItemID', 'like', "%{$searchKeyword}%")
        ->where(function ($query) use($values) {
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $query->orWhere('inventoryitem.InventoryItemID', '=', "%{$value}%");
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you have the ID then assuming thats a complete column content  an `=` would be better than a `like` and just explode your comma delim string to get an array of ID's

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've updated my question above, is it cool if you check it out? :)

Comment: ->whereIn('inventoryitem.InventoryItemID', explode(',', $searchKeyword))

Comment: you should remove the first where ->where('inventoryitem.InventoryItemID', 'like', "%{$searchKeyword}%"), it will filter out all the results because the condition will not match.

Comment: Split the input by comma and use the IN comperator

Comment: `->where(function ($query) use($values) {` should be `->orWhere(function ($query) use($values) {`.